# Подвисает курсор как от тачпада так и от мышки

Tags: windows

При работе, курсор виснет (на какое-то время) как будто не реагирует, я предполагал что это от работы JVM машины при запущенном докере, но и без докера замечаются подвисания. Кто может сталкивался, подскажите причину и решения его.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.